# Identifying the type of errors occurring in Qiskit hardware

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I want to identify the type of errors (for example, bit-flip error) occurring in specific hardware of Qiskit, for example, 'ibm_cairo'. But on the Qiskit website, I could only check

- the error rate for each qubit and each connection, and
- the basic gates of that hardware where the error can be applied.

It is possible to know the type of errors in specific hardware, and if I can, how can I know that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Table View on the website has a bit more numbers than what you've mentioned, like T1 and T2. Remember that the device doesn't tell us about its errors. We can only try to deduce them from experiments. The table as far as I know displays results of T1, T2, randomized benchmarking, and readout experiments.